# Detener la reproducción de un MediaPlayer y comenzar otra canción en Android

Tags: android

Buenas. Ando liado con un código de Android donde intento gestionar la música que se reproduce en una aplicación através de una clase. La idea es que cuando desde alguna activity se llame a la clase, detenga la canción que se estaba reproduciendo y empiece a reproducir otra. 
El código que tengo es este:

```
public class GestorAudio {
private String audioRecibido="";
private boolean audioLoop=false;
private MediaPlayer musica;
private Context context;

public void setMusica(String audioRecibido, boolean audioLoop,Context context){
    this.audioRecibido=audioRecibido;
    this.audioLoop=audioLoop;
    this.context=context;

    //Detenemos la música si se está reproduciendo:
    if(musica!=null && musica.isPlaying()){

        musica.stop();
        musica.release();
        musica=null;
    }

    //Elegimos el tema a reproducir:
    if(audioRecibido.equals("intro")){
        musica = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.music_intro);
    }
    if(audioRecibido.equals("otro")){
        musica = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.spirit);
    }

    //Indicamos si se reproduce o no en loop:
        musica.setLooping(audioLoop);

    //Iniciamos la música
        musica.start();



}}
```

La primera vez funciona, pero cuando llamo al método desde cualquier otra clase, si ya se está reproduciendo un audio, me da este error:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.frandalf.internhero.GestorAudio.setMusica(java.lang.String, boolean, android.content.Context)' on a null object reference
```

Por más vueltas que le doy y por más que pruebo cosas que encuentro por internet no me funciona. Entiendo que, ya que reproduce el primer audio, el problema debe estar en el proceso de parar y reiniciar el MediaPlayer. ¿Alguna idea?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Seguramente estas tratando de llamar un método en una instancia de `MediaPlayer` con valor null, para esto puedes usar un patron singleton que permita una ùnica instancia de `MediaPlayer`, puedes crear una clase como la siguiente:

```
public class MediaPlayerSingleton extends MediaPlayer{
    private static MediaPlayerSingleton mediaPlayerSingleton;

    private MediaPlayerSingleton() {}

        public static MediaPlayerSingleton getInstance() {
            synchronized (mediaPlayerSingleton)  { 
                if(mediaPlayerSingleton == null)
                    mediaPlayerSingleton = new MediaPlayerSingleton();
            }
            return mediaPlayerSingleton;
        }
    }
```

Para llamarlo desde cualquier clase se realizaría de esta forma:

```
MediaPlayerSingleton mediaPlayer = MediaPlayerSingleton.getInstance();
    mediaPlayer.play();
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero aún estoy un poco pez en esto de programar. ¿El singleton lo crearía dentro de mi propia clase? Es que no sé muy bien cómo encajarla, ni entiendo qué ocurre al llamar a mediaPlayer.play(); que me pones al final. ¿Podrías explicarlo un poco más o encajarlo todo en la clase que puse antes? Muchas gracias